# Is there a way to transform a list item to a popup?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to achieve a similar effect as shown in the gif. The List should also push away a bit.

[image: ListView PopUp]

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/expandable  You can also use this package

Answer (score 0):

Try making it a list of custom components component and on click / select you change it's properties to be bigger as in the gif. This might help: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html